# Update Specific Object in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I am currently developing a GUI for MATLAB which is updated using a (relatively) high frequency. It contains 3 Axes and a bunch of check boxes etc. In every iteration, I use the `drawnow` command to update everything - which works nice and dandy.

Little more background: the GUI is completely controlled via script. I use handlers to get the info I need.

The problem: I am running into performance issues. I am now looking for a way to update ONLY the checkbox status but leave everything else untouched. Currently I am not able to read back a changed checkbox status without using `drawnow` - and I am not able to find anything about updating specific objects.

Comment: There should be no need to use `drawnow`.. you need to give much more information for anyone to help you - ideally a working code showing the bottleneck you have.

Comment: @nirvana-msu `drawnow` is necessary here to flush the callback queue.

Comment: @Suever it should not affect _querying_ uicontrol checkbox status. True, the callback may not have been processed, but this is not what OP seems to have a problem with

Comment: @nirvana-msu Try it for yourself and you'll see that the `Value` property is not updated unless you call `drawnow`. Like this: `figure;c=uicontrol('style','check');plot(1);drawnow;while true;plot(1);disp(get(c,'value'));end`

Comment: @Suever, you are correct. I'm so much used to using native swing components that I did not even realize uicontrols have such issues. Posted another answer with example illustrating that `JCheckBox` works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to flush the event/callback queue without rendering the graphics, only the other way around. There is also no way to flush the event/callback queue for a specific graphics object which is required for the `Value` property of the `uicontrol` to be updated.

What you can do though, is rather than using the vanilla `drawnow`, consider using the `limitrate` input to `drawnow` which ensures that if you are updating your plots at a very high frequency, they are only actually rendered at a maximum of 20 frames per second. This will prevent you from having a significant lag due to all of the render events.

```
drawnow limitrate
```

From the documentation:

> `drawnow limitrate` limits the number of updates to 20 frames per second. If it has been fewer than 50 milliseconds since the last update, or if the graphics renderer is busy with the previous change, then drawnow discards the new updates. Use this command if you are updating graphics objects in a loop and do not need to see every update on the screen. Skipping updates can create faster animations. Pending callbacks are processed, so you can interact with figures during animations.

And as an example:

```
hcheck = uicontrol('style', 'check', 'String', 'Green');
hplot = plot(rand(10,1));
set(gca, 'ylim', [0 1], 'xlim', [1 10])

originalColor = get(hplot, 'Color');

while true
    set(hplot, 'YData', rand(10,1))

    if get(hcheck, 'value')
        set(hplot, 'Color', 'g')
    else
        set(hplot, 'Color', originalColor)
    end

    drawnow limitrate
end
```

[image]

Running that example on my Mac, without using the `limitrate` option, I was able to loop through the `while` loop about 42 times per second. With the `limitrate` option enabled, I was able to loop through 767 times per second.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using pure swing components, such as `JCheckBox`. They do not have such issues as uicontrols do. Try running the below example and you'll see that you *can* query new checkbox state right after it changes, without having to use `drawnow`:

```
figure();
jCB = javaObjectEDT(javax.swing.JCheckBox('Green',0));
javacomponent(jCB, [20, 20, 60, 20], gcf);
pause(0.1);

while true
    plot(1);   % just some random code
    display(jCB.isSelected());
end
```

So you don't necessarily need to flush the even queue to query the updated graphics state.